# replace collection window in winform propertygrid control

Tags: c#, propertygrid

a  winform propertygrid will popup a new window when its datasource contained a collection,I want to use my own winform when popup the window.

eg:
`Class User{ int ID ;int Name; list<order> CustomerOrder;}`,when popup the order page,I want it can pick order from exist order list where from another datasource when add the item.

does this can be true? or opensource extended  control or 3rd control ?

Answer (score 1):

If you make a new type that wraps your list or orders, you can set the Editor attribute on your new type and then you can pop up any kind of winform you desire.

For example, wrapping the List with a class like this:

```
[Editor(typeof(OrderListEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
class OrderList
{
    public OrderList() { Orders = new List<order>(); }
    public List<order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

and having the property of your user class:

```
class User
{
...
    public OrderList CustomerOrder { get; }
}
```

Then all you have to do is write the logic to do what you want when the user presses the '...' button in the PropertyGrid:

```
class OrderListEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        OrderList list = (OrderList)value;

        Console.WriteLine("There are " + list.Orders.Count + " orders");
        return list;
    }
}
```